# Can I attach a C++ Garbage Collector to a Java program making JNI Calls to C/C++ libraries?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, java-native-interface, solaris

I have a Java application with lots of JNI calls, in different C++ libraries.
Sometimes there libraries call/link to other shared libraries.
I was thinking of attaching "libgc" the garbage collector on Solaris to the "Native" side of the code.
How do I do it?

1. Is it enough if I link libgc with the C/C++ library?
2. How do I know the garbage collection is working?
3. Do I need to link libgc to all native libraries or is any one enough?

OS:Solaris

Comment: Sounds interesting, but what do you want to do exactly? Use gc triggers to free memory in native libs?

Comment: @Andreas_D Yes, I want the native libs also 'garbage collected'

Comment: I would like to point out that the same shared libraries are used by other pure C++ programs. Thus, would there be a problem there? i.e. a few libraries being Garbage Collected, but most not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. Write tests similar to [this](http://pastebin.ch/6072).
3. You need to link `libgc` to all libraries that are using it. Link it dynamically if the platform supports it.

Comment: So what happens if I get 90% of the libraries, but miss out one. Nothing catastrophic right? (I am okay with a few leaks not getting caught).

Comment: @KGA I don't understand what you mean by "but miss out one". If your library make calls to `gc_malloc` or something similar, it has to be linked with `libgc`. If `libgc` is dynamically linked, your JVM will crash if it is not able to find the `libgc` shared library at runtime.

Comment: My (Java/JNI) program links to about 10-15 C++ shared libraries. Let's say I compile 14 of those with libgc, forget one of them. This 15th library (to which JNI calls are made) is not linked to libgc, will it use libC's malloc and calloc? AND will it interfere with libgc?

Comment: Note: My libraries are going to be linked statically via -lgc. I hope that is not a problem.

Comment: Also, what happens to a pure C++ program (that also shares some libraries with the JNI). When one of it's dynamically linked libraries is linked to libgc, but rest of program is not?

Comment: @KGA 15th library will call the default `malloc` and `calloc`.

Comment: This might seem persistent, but I need to understand how both libgc and JNI work. What if library A (libgc attached) allocates memory, passes it to library B(no libgc) via pointer. Two more possibilities here: library B leaks the memory, frees the memory. What happens? Any pointers to where to read up on technical working of both libgc and JNI memory allocation?

Comment: @KGA The GC in library `A` will release the memory but I am not sure if it will be aware of the reference in `B`.